# Как создать модель базы данних Entity Framework на основе существующей в коде?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я хочу что бы по строке подключения в DbContext сформировалась модель не создавая классы для DbSet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
namespace Project
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(@"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Base; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Application Name=EntityFramework");
        }
    }
}
```

И вообще возможно ли такое?
Мне нужно это для динамической модель, может есть другие пути создания динамической модели EF.
Суть задачи: чтобы я во время работы программы я мог написать имя базы данных и создалась ее модель.

Comment: Я хотел бы динамически создавать Context модели.

Comment: @A K Это не совсем то. Мне надо что бы во время работы программы можно было создать модель на основе любой базы данных.

Comment: EF для этого не подходит. Программы типа SSMS не используют EF. Пишите свои запросы, получайте список таблиц. За основу возьмите например: https://stackoverflow.com/q/175415/5752652

Comment: @A K тогда как. Использовать Linq to SQL?

Comment: Хорошо, создалась модель. Дальше что? Как вы будете использовать созданную модель? PS: Вот честно, достали такие вопросы: "хочу динамически использовать то, не знаю что".